# How to Add a Default Image to SharePoint 2010 Custom List Instance Image Column

Tags: list, sharepoint

I'm creating a custom list definition in Visual Studio for SharePoint 2010.  In the list definition elements file, I've provided some default values for the list instance as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<ListInstance Title="News"
            OnQuickLaunch="FALSE"
            TemplateType="10000"
            Url="Lists/News"
            Description="Contains news articles related to happenings at Corporate.">
<Data>
  <Rows>
    <Row>
      <!-- Default list data -->
      <Field Name="Photo">http://myserver/sites/foobar/Style%20Library/Images/Custom/myimage.png</Field>
      <Field Name="Title">My Title</Field>
      <Field Name="Body">My article.</Field>
      <Field Name="Modified">12-21-2012</Field>
      <Field Name="Author">99;#mydomain\bsmith</Field>
      <Field Name="Expires">01-22-2013</Field>
    </Row>
  </Rows>
</Data>
```

The default list is successfully created with the values above, except that the Photo and Author columns are displaying as blank.  Any ideas on how I can populate those columns correctly?  I know the photo URL is valid as I can browse to it.  And another posting pointed me to the "99;#" prefix for the author column--without the prefix, every column in the list displays as blank.

Also, here are the list schema fields, if it matters:

```
<Field ID="{d3a92d97-2b77-4a25-9698-3ab54874bc17}"
         Name="Photo" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" ShowInEditForm="TRUE"
         Type="Image" DisplayName="Photo"
         Required="TRUE"></Field>
  <Field ID="{d3a92d97-2b77-4a25-9698-3ab54874bc11}"
         Name="Title"
         Type="Text" DisplayName="Title"
         Required="TRUE"></Field>
  <Field ID="{d3a92d97-2b77-4a25-9698-3ab54874bc16}"
         Name="Body"
         Type="Note" DisplayName="Body"
         Required="TRUE" NumLines="100"></Field>
  <Field ID="{d3a92d97-2b77-4a25-9698-3ab54874bc13}"
         Name="Modified"
         Type="DateTime" DisplayName="Modified"
         Required="TRUE"></Field>
  <Field ID="{d3a92d97-2b77-4a25-9698-3ab54874bc14}"
         Name="Author"
         Type="Text" DisplayName="Author"
         Required="FALSE"></Field>
  <Field ID="{d3a92d97-2b77-4a25-9698-3ab54874bc15}"
         Name="Expires"
         Type="DateTime" DisplayName="Expires"
         Required="FALSE"></Field>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try provisioning your field data like this in your list instance.

```
<Field Name="Photo"><![CDATA[<IMG SRC="/sites/foobar/Style%20Library/Images/Custom/myimage.png"></IMG>]]></Field>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks Chuck!  That was it.  This doesn't resolve the author issue, but I should probably open another question for that anyway.  I just put them together here in case it was the same issue, which it turned out not to be.